# Git commits showing in git log but changes not appearing in files

Tags: git, config

I have a master server for configs and a few nodes that take the config updates. The config is a single file in a directory and the .gitignore ignores everything but the config. When I change it on the master and add and commit it, I then push it to all remotes (all nodes) and it works just fine, shows IPs and success. But then when I "git pull" on the nodes it does show that it got a new commit and git log shows all of them properly, but the file remains unchanged in the working tree. Both servers are on the master branch. Neither git fetch -> git merge nor git pull works.

Comment: can you `git blame` on that file and see if another commit also modified that line of code?

Comment: What do you mean by you "push it to all nodes"?  If you then "pull" on those same nodes, what are you pulling?  What did you push?  (In general, you will get the best answers if you show actual commands and their outputs, i.e., provide a small, self-contained example.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)